# When working in an AI file at 1/6th scale, will raster images in the document maintain their native quality when scaling up to full size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, resize

I'm designing a 36"x48" poster in Adobe Illustrator and I want to work at 1/6th scale to keep file size low.

I have to include raster images as part of this project. Working at 1/6th scale means that I'll have to shrink those down within Illustrator.

So my question is, when this is scaled up from 1/6th to full dimensions, will the raster images maintain their original quality? Also, does embedding vs. linking the raster images make a difference here? I want to keep my working file size low without sacrificing quality on the raster images within the AI doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unlike raster image editors, Illustrator does **not** interpolate raster data. The pixel data in a raster image remains the same, regardless of what one does in terms of scaling the image within Illustrator.

**Quick Answer:** It **is possible** to place something like a 300PPI image into an Illustrator document, reduce the image within Illustrator to 1/6th scale. If the image is then output "at size" (x6, i.e. the original image size 100%) the PPI will *still* be 300PPI upon output.

---

**Longer Answer:**

Example (using simple dimensions for clarity):

A 6" x 6"  image @ 300ppi has a total pixel count of 3,240,000 pixels (3.24 megapixels). 
6" * 300PPI = 1,800 (pixel dimension). So, 1,800px * 1,800px = 3,240,000px

<sup>[ pixel width multiplied by pixel height = total pixels ]</sup>

With Illustrator, if this image is ***reduced***, to say 3"x3", the total number of pixels does **not** change. The **effective PPI** changes. In other words, Illustrator "condenses" the total number pixels into the new dimensions, meaning the change *effectively* alters the image PPI. So at 3x3" the image is now 600ppi. An image reduced by 50% will *effectively* double the image PPI.

In order to figure the effective PPI for a raster image one works backwards....

- √3,240,000 = 1,800 / 3" = 600ppi 
  (square root of total pixels, divided by dimension, equals *effective* pixels per inch)

Conversely if the image is ***enlarged***, to say 12"x12", in Illustrator the total number of pixels are *stretched* to fill the enlarged dimensions, but the PPI remains the same. Again, the **effective PPI** of the image is changed not the *actual* pixel data. An image enlarged by 200% will *effectively* half the PPI.

Working backwards....

- √3,240,000 = 1,800 / 12" = 150ppi 
  (square root of total pixels, divided by dimension, equals *effective* pixels per inch)

---

So, to answer the question `:)`...

If you place a 300PPI image into Illustrator, you can reduce/enlarge it as you please, but you **won't** change the image pixel data.

So, if the image is enlarged too much the overall image quality *may* suffer due to less PPI upon output. It's best to place the image at the desired *output size and resolution*, then reduce and never enlarge the image beyond it's original dimensions.

It's possible to watch the **Effective PPI** of raster images when you are scaling them within Illustrator by using the **Document Info Panel** (`Window > Document Info` then choose "Linked/Embedded Images" from the panel menu, whichever is appropriate)

Here, I've used a 6"x6" @300PPI raster image from Photoshop and **linked** to it in Illustrator. Note in the panel the `Size` remains the *same* - 1,800px x 1,800px - at all times. *However*, as I reduce the image, the *effective PPI*, i.e. `Resolution`, changes along with the `Dimensions`.

[image]
<sub>This is using Illustrator CS6, but it's the same info shown in more recent releases</sub>
<sup>- the panel will merely appear different.</sup>

Linking or Embedding doesn't change any of this PPI behavior. Here you can see an **embedded** image operates in the same manner:

[image]

However, Linking/Embedding *may* alter what's possible while working within Illustrator, i.e. some Illustrator operations only work with embedded raster images.

---

Reducing/enlarging raster images within Illustrator will not "speed up" operations. Illustrator will *always* work with the total number of pixels within the image.

## Be Aware...

The menu item `Effects > Document Raster Effects Settings` has **absolutely nothing to do with any linked or embedded raster image**. It **won't** change any of the above described behavior nor alter any raster image pixel data. It has **no relation** to *any* linked or embedded raster images.

This menu items refers to "live" **effects** within Illustrator which auto-generate raster images. Effects such as glows, drop shadows, blurs, etc. all generate embedded raster images "on-the-fly" to create their appearance. It's the resolution of *those* auto-generated images which the menu item refers.

Reducing the PPI for the `Document Raster Effects Settings` *can* speed up operations within an Illustrator file *if* you are using such raster *effects*. Illustrator can auto-generate a 72ppi raster effect faster than it generates a 300ppi raster effect. A "speed trick" for high resolution output is often to work with this setting at 72ppi. Then, before output, increase the setting to 300ppi, wait for everything to redraw, then output.

---

I'd also point out that where *raster images* are concerned, this "effective PPI" behavior is *identical* in both **Adobe Illustrator** *and* **Adobe InDesign**.